# How do I install a boot manager that works with Ubuntu and Windows 8? (Legacy)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot

I'm in an interesting place.  I have both Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 installed on different partitions, both accessed through legacy boot.  This machine came with UEFI by default.  Anyway, the only way I can switch between the tow OSes is by changing which one has the "boot" flag from a Ubuntu live USB.

How can I install a boot manager after having the OSes already installed, where I can select which one I want to use when I turn my computer on?

Comment: Windows 8 Bootloader and Grub2 both support one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can boot by moving boot flag, then you have to have installed grub2's boot loader to the PBR - partition boot sector. Windows boots from MBR to PBR of the Windows partition which has more Windows boot code.

Grub does not use boot flag and is not normally installed to a PBR, but installed to the MBR. Then from grub menu you can boot either Ubuntu or Windows.

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot.:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  I installed boot repair and did the recommended repair and I can now finally choose which OS to boot.  (something I have not had once with this computer)